# Trying to get a total - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get the total cost in one of my field called "upgrade_cost" and store that in a variable called $tuc

```
  def totalUpgradeCost
    $e = Experience.all
      $tuc = 0
      (e.emf_assets).each do |i|
        i.upgrade_cost += $tuc
      end
    return $tuc
  end
```

I'm getting some error undefined local variable or method `e', new to ruby. Anyone help?

Comment: Why are you using global variables with `$`? Pretty sure you don't need this; lose the `$`! Note that Ruby is *not* Perl or PHP ;-) (This is, by the way, also your error).

Comment: ok thanks :) now i'm getting error: undefined method `emf_assets'  lol

Comment: what is `emf_assets`?

Comment: How do your relations and models look like?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `emf_assets` are associated (via `has_many`) with an experience. That said I think the following could work for you:

```
def total_upgrade_cost
  total = 0                               # use a more descriptive variable names
  all_experiences = Experience.all        

  all_experiences.each do |experience|    # iterate over each `experiment`
    experience.emf_assets.each do |asset| # load `emf_assets` for each `experiment`

      # add the `upgrade_cost` (which might be `nil`) to `total`
      total += asset.upgrade_cost.to_i    
    end
  end

  total                                   # no need for an explicit `return`
end
```

Please note that this might work for smaller numbers of `experiences` and `emf_assets`, but in a next step performance will benefit from some optimization. But I think that optimization is out of the scope of this question at the moment. You will need to avoid the N+1 query problem and it might makes sense to do the whole calculation in your database.

Comment: @Stefan, ty :) I have one-to-many (exp > assets). So i was getting error Nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError). This somehow fixed it                   all_experiences.each do |experience|    
      experience.emf_assets.each do |asset|
        if asset.upgrade_cost != nil 
          total += asset.upgrade_cost
        else
          asset.upgrade_cost += 0
        end
      end
    end

Comment: it's adding total cost nicely now :O

Comment: Thanks! :) That would solve my answer. I didn't know there was to_i. Is that to Int? I was trying to complicate things by doing an if statement.

Comment: Yes, `to_i` tries to translate the value into an integer. `nil.to_i` returns `0`

Answer (score 0):

What is the `e` in `e.emf_assets`? If you mean `$e`, you aren't allowed to drop the `$`. In Ruby, a `$` at the start of a variable name indicates a global variable. If you aren't using `$e` outside of this function anyway, it would be better to call it simply `e`, so that it wouldn't be visible outside of the function. Regardless, you're getting an error because `$e` refers to a global, and `e` refers to a separate (undefined) local variable.

Answer (score -2):

This is not PHP. `$` sign isn't required everywhere. You've used `$` with one `e` and left another empty, that's why the error.

This code should work:

```
def totalUpgradeCost
  e = Experience.all
  tuc = 0
  e.emf_assets.each do |i|
    tuc += i.upgrade_cost
  end

  return tuc
end
```

This is doable in shorter way:

```
def totalUpgradeCost
  e = Experience.all
  e.emf_assets.inject(0) {|sum, i| sum += i.upgrade_cost}
end
```

Comment: ...for introducing functional programming to someone who can't even look at two variables and understand that they are different.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Besides naming (total_upgrade_cost) this should work.

Comment: It's unlikely that `Experience.all.emf_assets` works.

Comment: ty babar! seems like the doable way is  too complicated for me xdd